# How to find length/size of a key in a MultivaluedMap?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, hashmap, multivalue

```
MultivaluedMap map= new MultivaluedMapImpl();
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "compress;q=0.5");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.1");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.2");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.3");
```

How can I find the size of the key "Accept-Encoding"?

Answer (score 2):

`MultivaluedMap<K, V>` implements `Map<K,List<V>>` so

```
((Map<String,List<String>>)map).get("Accept-Encoding").size();
```

---

Now I see that you use non generic version (which is not a good idea):

```
Map tmp = map instanceof Map ? (Map) map : new HashMap();
// because you don't use generic you should get value as an Object instance
Object value = tmp.get("Accept-Encoding");
// by default we assume that there the value is not a List instance
int size = 0;    

// for security we check that the value instance implements List interface
if (value instanceof List) {
    // we check size of that list
    size = ((List) value).size();
}
```

Short version (and without checking):

```
((List) ((Map) map).get("Accept-Encoding")).size();
```

You should see why using generic version is better than raw version.

Comment: Hi Lukas, Can you please find the updated code and suggest me.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.get(itr.next()).size()`

Code:

```
MultivaluedMap map= new MultivaluedMapImpl();
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "compress;q=0.5");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.1");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.2");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.3");

Iterator itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(map.get(itr.next()).size());
        }
```